# String matching without using builtin functions

Tags: string, matlab

I want to search for a query (a string) in a subject (another string).

The query may appear in whole or in parts, but will not be rearranged. For instance, if the query is `'da'`, and the subject is `'dura'`, it is still a match.

I am not allowed to use string functions like `strfind` or `find`.

Comment: Look into [`regexp`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexp.html) or [`regexpi`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexpi.html).

Comment: If you can't use functions, even such as `regexp`, you can step through the input string character by character and compare to the match string. Other than that, please show the code you've tried!

Answer (score 0):

If this is homework, I suggest you look at the explanation which precedes the code and then try for yourself, before looking at the actual code.

The code below looks for all occurrences of chars of the `query` string within the `subject` string (variables `m`; and related `ii`, `jj`). It then tests all possible orders of those occurrences (variable `test`). An order is "acceptable" if it contains all desired chars (`cond1`) in increasing positions (`cond2`). The result (variable `result`) is affirmative if there is at least one acceptable order.

```
subject = 'this is a test string';
query = 'ten';

m = bsxfun(@eq, subject.', query);
%'// m: test if each char of query equals each char of subject
[ii jj] = find(m);
jj = jj.'; %'// ii: which char of query is found within subject...
ii = ii.'; %'// jj: ... and at which position
test = nchoosek(1:numel(jj),numel(query)).'; %'// test all possible orders
cond1 = all(jj(test) == repmat((1:numel(query)).',1,size(test,2)));
%'// cond1: for each order, are all chars of query found in subject?
cond2 = all(diff(ii(test))>0);
%//  cond2: for each order, are the found chars in increasing positions?
result = any(cond1 & cond2); %// final result: 1 or 0
```

The code could be improved by using a better approach as regards to `test`, i.e. not testing all possible orders given by `nchoosek`.

Answer (score 0):

<s>Matlab allows you to view the source of built-in functions, so you could always try reading the code to see how the Matlab developers did it (although it will probably be very complex).</s> (thanks Luis for the correction)

Finding a string in another string is a basic computer science problem. You can read up on it in any number of resources, such as [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_matching).

Your requirement of non-rearranging partial matches recalls the bioinformatics problem of mapping splice variants to a genomic sequence.

You may solve your problem by using a sequence alignment algorithm such as [Smith-Waterman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith-Waterman_algorithm), modified to work with all English characters and not just DNA bases.

Is this question actually from bioinformatics? If so, you should tag it as such.

Comment: Actually, not all Matlab's functions have accessible source code. Precisely, those functions that Matlab calls "built-in" are _not_ written in Matlab code (presumably for speed reasons). If you try `type strfind` it will just print `'strfind' is a built-in function`, so no source code available.

Answer (score 0):

The constraints make this actually quite straightforward with a single loop. Imagine you have two indices initially pointing at the first character of both strings, now compare them - if they don't match, increment the subject index and try again. If they do, increment both. If you've reached the end of the query at that point, you've found it. The actual implementation should be simple enough, and I don't want to do *all* the work for you ;)